# Qual a diferença entre as formas de pesquisa LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Qual a diferença entre:

```
var query =  from s in db.DetailsRaWeb
             where s.cod_cli.Equals(Cod_Cli) && s.tag.Equals(TAG)
             select s;
```

e isso:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.cod_cli.Equals(Cod_Cli) && s.tag.Equals(TAG));
```

Pelo que entendi, a primeira realiza a consulta propriamente dita,  e a segunda filtra a consulta?